# Computing the Jacobian matrix in symplectic Euler integration

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I am reading a book about [geometric numerical integration](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540306634). In the text, they present Euler symplectic integration

\begin{equation}
p_{n+1}=p_n-hH_q(p_{n+1},q_n)\\
q_{n+1} = q_n+hH_p(p_{n+1},q_n)
\end{equation}

for integrating the Hamiltonian system
\begin{align}
\dot{p}=-H_q(p,q)\\
\dot{q}=H_p(p,q)
\end{align}

In the book it is written that differentiating the first system (symplectic integration scheme) with respect to $(p_n,q_n)$ yields

$$\begin{bmatrix}
I+hH_{qp}^T &0\\
-hH_{pp}& I
\end{bmatrix}
(\frac{\partial(p_{n+1},q_{n+1})}{\partial (p_n,q_n)}) =
\begin{bmatrix}
I &-H_{qq}\\
0& I+hH_{qp}
\end{bmatrix}$$

I think I understand where the matrix on the right side comes from since it is the jacobian matrix of $$f(p_n,q_n) =\begin{bmatrix}p_n-hH_q(p_{n+1},q_n)\\
q_n+hH_p(p_{n+1},q_n)\end{bmatrix}$$ with respect to $(p_n,q_n)$ but I don't really understand how we get the expression on the left, i.e. where does

$$\begin{bmatrix}
I+hH_{qp}^T &0\\
-hH_{pp}& I
\end{bmatrix}
(\frac{\partial(p_{n+1},q_{n+1})}{\partial (p_n,q_n)}) $$ come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to fully write out the total differentials of the equations, then you get
\begin{align}
dp_{n+1}&=dp_n-hH_{qp}dp_{n+1}-hH_{qq}dq_n\\
dq_{n+1}&=dq_n+hH_{pp}dp_{n+1}+hH_{pq}dq_n
\end{align}
Now sort the components with the same index to each side and write it in matrix form
$$
\pmatrix{I+hH_{qp}&0\\-hH_{pp}&I}\pmatrix{dp_{n+1}\\dq_{n+1}}
=
\pmatrix{I&-hH_{qq}\\0&I+H_{pq}}\pmatrix{dp_n\\dq_n}
$$
Then insert the vector field $(\frac\partial{\partial p_n},\frac\partial{\partial q_n})$ to get the claimed identity.

Comment: That is, re-express $dp_{n+1} = \partial_{p_{n}} p_{n+1}d p_n + \partial_{q_n} p_{n+1} d q_n$ and identically for $dq_{n+1}$. This provides us with the desired result.